# Concatenation with 2 strings

Tags: c, string, character, concatenation

I've seen methods of doing this with "strcopy" and "strcat", but I'm not allowed to use any predefined string functions.

I'm given:

```
    void str_cat_101(char const input1[], char const input2[], char result[]);
```

And I have to put the characters from input1 and input2 into the result (from left to right). Would I have to use two for loops, with variables i and j to represent the two different strings in my argument list? I know how to copy values from one string, but I'm confused as to how I would transfer values from two. Thanks for the help.

So here's what I have in my string.c file, but I feel like I didn't do it the right way.

```
void str_cat_101(char const input1[], char const input2[], char result[])
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; input1[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      result[i] = input1[i];
   }
   result[i] = '\0';
   for (j = 0; input2[j] != '\0'; j++)
   {
      result[j] = input2[j];
   }
   result[j] = '\0';
}
```

And here are my test cases:

```
void str_cat_101_tests(void)
{
   char input1[4] = {'k', 'a', 'r', '\0'};
   char input2[3] = {'e', 'n', '\0'};
   char result[7];

   str_cat_101(input1, input2, result);
   checkit_string("karen", result);
}

int main()
{
   str_cat_101_tests();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just do the same thing twice. Start the copying the second one where you finished copying the first.

Comment: Show what you've tried, we're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I should've included what I did. Sorry if it seems like I'm trying to get you guys do do my homework. I appreciate everyone who posts hints and ideas on how to get the problem done and I would never use this site just to get my homework written for me. I'm just a really confused student who's completely new to programming. :) And I"ll definitely edit my question to include what I did so far. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void str_cat_101(char const input1[], char const input2[], char result[])
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; input1[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      result[i] = input1[i];
   }
//   result[i] = '\0';
   for (j = 0; input2[j] != '\0'; j++)
   {
      result[i+j] = input2[j];//Copy to the location of the continued
   }
   result[i+j] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like(*read comment*):

```
void str_cat_101(char const input1[], char const input2[], char result[]){
  int i=0, j=0;
  while(input1[j]) // copy input1
    result[i++] = input1[j++];
  --i;
  j=0;
  while(input2[j]) // append intput2
    result[i++] = input2[j++];           
  result[i]='\0';
}
```

`result[]` should be sufficiently large that is `strlen(input1) + strlen(input2) + 1`

**Edit**:

Just correct you second loop, you are to append into `result[]` instead recopying from zero location in result:

```
   for (j = 0; input2[j] != '\0'; j++, i++) // notice i++
   {
      result[i] = input2[j];   // notice `i` in index with result 
   } 
   result[i] = '\0';  // notice `i`
```

Comment: What part of "I'm not allowed to use any predefined string functions" did you not understand?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't use any predefined string functions so I don't think I can use strcpy or strcat. :( Thanks though.

Comment: So I changed my second for loop, as you said above, but the test still isn't passing. :( I'll put my test case above.

Comment: @Karen ..its just running fine, here is [**link I tested online**](http://ideone.com/d3e2kX) ..

Comment: Yeah, I found a typo in what I wrote on my Terminal window, thanks though!

Comment: Oh, one quick question, the "i" in the second for loop, is that the same "i" that we left off upon in the first for loop?

Comment: @karen Yes! you can't change value of `i` between two loop,

Answer (score 0):

If you can use linked lists instead of arrays for input string, all you have to do is set the pointer of last character of string 1 to the head of string 2 and you are done. If Linked list is not an option, then you may use extra space to store both strings by traversing them using one loop.